# Skip NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException when two table has same column names

Tags: hibernate, jpa

My existing application is using HibernateDAOSupport and hibernateTemplate with version 3.6.10.
When I have a native query like below then it works fine with current system.

```
select a.name, b.name from a inner join b on a.bid=b.id
```

Now I am upgrading my application to JPA so it throws me error : 
NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException

I can fix this error by changing query to below one:

```
select a.name as aname, b.name from a inner join b on a.bid=b.id
```

But the problem is my application is huge and finding out these queries would be tedious. Want to know if there is any setting where I can skip this error to throw.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this is not possible according to the documentation:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-multi-entity-query

> Column alias injection is needed in the following query which
>   otherwise throws NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException.